# Retriving data from SQLite in the range of 3 days before current date and 3 days after

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

What I am trying to achieve is retrieve records from SQLite database which are in the range of 3 days before current date and 3 days after current date including current date.

How it can be done ?

Comment: -1 show us the code you already have.

Comment: what is the type of date field in your table? i mean string , int ???

Comment: Why -1 ? u could have asked for it in first place.
what i have is the code for current date.i am a bit lost at how it can be done for +3 and -3 days thats why i asked here..!

Comment: String.. @KalpeshLakhani

Comment: post your code here, what error you are getting.

Comment: i am not able to find the idea of how to go about it.i want suggestion of how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dates are stored in the format expected by SQLite date functions, i.e., `yyyy-mm-dd`, you can use the [`date` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to make computations on dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateCol BETWEEN date('now', '-3 days') AND date('now', '3 days')
```